# How to insert one record into a table with an IDENTITY column

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

Is it possible to insert only one record in one column on a table?

I have a table `EMP_MASTERTBL` with columns

```
MASTERID | USERID | EMPNO | LASTNAME | FIRSTNAME | REGION | COUNTRY | ENTITY | LOCATION | JOBTITLE
```

I need to add a new job title in one particular employee so I used this code/query

```
INSERT INTO EMP_MASTERTBL (MASTERID, JOBTITLE) VALUES ('7634', 'Manager')
```

But I got this error message

> Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table
>   'EMP_MASTERTBL' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

I only need to add another job title to one particular employee. Employee can have multiple job titles.

Thank you.

Comment: If this is `SQL-Server`, it is because the table `EMP_MASTERTBL` has the column `MASTER_ID` set with an `IDENTITY(...,...)` which prevent you from insert a value to it. Check out this link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188059.aspx

Comment: MySql is something altogether different from SQL Server

Comment: Your data model supports only one title per employee. With a relational design, you need another table for a one-to-many relationship to allow a single employee to have multiple titles.

Comment: Are you trying to change the job title for a particular employee that already exists in the table?  If so, then you need an `UPDATE` statement and not `INSERT`.

Comment: @ChrisDunawayI'm not trying to change the job title. I'm trying to add the job title because one employee can have multiple job titles.

Answer (score 2):

In SQL Server Studio, run this command first before the `INSERT` statement. You must have `ALTER` permission on this table to run this.

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT EMP_MASTERTBL ON;
```

Comment: I already tried this and I run again my query which is INSERT INTO EMP_MASTERTBL (MASTERID, JOBTITLE) VALUES ('7634', 'Manager') but I got this error 'Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_EMP_MASTERTBL'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.EMP_MASTERTBL'. The duplicate key value is (76237).
The statement has been terminated.'

Comment: Then that is a different error. It means that there is already a record with the value 76237 in the field MASTERID in the table. (PRIMARY KEY violation).

Comment: Why you need to do that? in that case there is no point in defining the column as `IDENITY`. rather, you should remove the identity column from insert list.

Answer (score 2):

don't put value to MASTERID because it will be automatically generated. try this:

```
INSERT INTO EMP_MASTERTBL (JOBTITLE) VALUES ('Manager')
```

Comment: I rather liked this answer which is by far correct to me

Comment: the jobtitle will be added but in different masterid or employee?

Comment: There are many ways to solve this problem.You need to pay attention to the error message.

Answer (score 0):

It may not be possible especially when you have defined the columns as not null. The best way to add the title would be using the update statement like this: UPDATE EMP_MASTERTBL SET JOBTILE = 'Manager' WHERE USERID = 'EMPLOYEE'S_USERID';
NB: Avoid the quotes on userid if the userid is an integer.

Comment: But it will only change the first job title and the new job title will never be added. Right?

Comment: Yeah, I think I missed that particular detail in the question. Not sure if it is possible to add a new one to an existing one or in better terms appending a new title to an existing one

Answer (score 0):

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT EMP_MASTERTBL ON;
GO
INSERT INTO EMP_MASTERTBL (MASTERID, JOBTITLE) VALUES ('7634', 'Manager')
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT EMP_MASTERTBL OFF;
```